# text box are getting cut off in iphone lay out

Tags: javascript, html, css

when you reduce the browser window to iphone lay out....
you can see the different lay out....
the problem is right side of the text fields are being cut off...
how to fix it...
providing my code below.....

http://jsfiddle.net/jPvzL/1/

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Company Name " name="fullname" maxlength="30" required="required" id="id_username">
<input type="text" placeholder="Contact Name" name="company" maxlength="30" required="required" id="id_company">
<input type="text" placeholder="Address1" name="email" maxlength="75" required="required" id="id_email">
<input type="password" placeholder="Address2" name="password" maxlength="16" required="required" id="id_password">
<input type="password" placeholder="Address3" name="repassword" required="required" id="id_repassword">
<input type="text" placeholder="City " name="fullname" maxlength="30" required="required" id="id_username">
<div class="controls">
    <select name="select" id="state" style="width: 300px;height: 38px;">
        <option value="California" selected="">California</option>
        <option value="New York">New York</option>
        <option value="Texas">Texas</option>
    </select>
</div>
<input type="text" placeholder="Zip" name="email" maxlength="75" required="required" id="id_email">
<div class="controls">
    <select name="select" id="country" style="width: 300px;height: 38px;">
        <option value="USA" selected="">USA</option>
        <option value="India">India</option>
        <option value="Korea">Korea</option>
        <option value="Vietnam">Vietnam</option>
    </select>
</div>
<input type="text" placeholder="Phone" name="company" maxlength="30" required="required" id="id_company">
<input type="text" placeholder="Fax" name="email" maxlength="75" required="required" id="id_email">
<input type="password" placeholder="Email" name="password" maxlength="16" required="required" id="id_password">
<input type="text" placeholder="URL" name="company" maxlength="30" required="required" id="id_company">
<input type="text" placeholder="GL Account" name="email" maxlength="75" required="required" id="id_email">
<input type="password" placeholder="" name="password" maxlength="16" required="required" id="id_password">
<textarea name="inquiry" placeholder="Notes" rows="3" required="required" id="id_inquiryForm" style="width:290px;"></textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your #signup-modal div is set to a width of 125px. Just increase it to be the correct sizes to fit the inputs. Or remove 'overflow:hidden'

Answer (score 0):

Had this issue a few weeks ago.  I don't know what your CSS looks like, but try adding a percentage width to your input fields:

```
form input{width: 99%;}
```

YMMV.  You may also have to add something for your textarea and select fields and tweak the percentage as needed.

Comment: You have some fixed widths that are extremely small, like on the #signup-modal form and #signup-modal.  In Chrome Dev Tools, I removed them or replaced them with a percentage and the form fields responded and flexed nicely.  Change the fixed width on any parent div directly affecting the form.

Comment: Ok here's a few tweaks I made for you: http://jsfiddle.net/maEZr/
my additions are marked with /*added by sarah*/

I didn't align the input and select fields, but you'll get the idea that the percentages will help you adjust the width and get them to fit exactly the way you need them to, no matter what screen size you are using.

Comment: thanks for your reply did you add this line alone #signup-modal form, #login-modal form {
    text-align:center
    /*added by sarah*/
    width: 59%;

Comment: I believe I added something else. just do a quick search for "sarah" in the css and you will find everything I tweaked.